# Define type synonym using a specific class

Tags: haskell, types

I'm still sometime lost in syntax of Haskell but this time I am not sure it is possible to do what I am trying to do.

What I would like to have is

```
import System.IO

class (Eq l, Show l) => Label l -- assume there might be some `where ...`

type Edge l = Label l => (Int, l, Int) -- my attempt on restricting l to be Label
type Graph l = [Edge l] -- inherently requiring l to be Label

addEdge :: Graph l -> Edge l -> Graph l
addEdge g e = e : g

data MyLabel = A | B | C deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Label MyLabel

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ show $ addEdge [] (1, A, 2) -- producing Graph MyLabel
    putStrLn $ show $ addEdge [] (1, 3, 2) -- not passing type checks
```

What I could do, is add the `Label l =>` contexts to all functions like `addEdge` but that would still allow instances of `Graph` with labels not conforming to the class `Label` and it would also duplicate the constraints. On the other hand, having the constraint in the type (somehow) would save a lot of work (there could never simply be any instance of `Edge`/`Graph` without the proper label type).

Can I somehow do it in Haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first off, `type` in Haskell does not declare a new type. `type` is strictly a type alias, and what you're asking for at a minimum requires an actual new type of the kind you get with `data` or `newtype`.

Now, that being said what you want can't completely be done in haskell - that is, you can't say "Anytime you see `Edge l`, there's an implicit constraint on `l` that says `(Label l)`".

What you *can* do, with the `GADTs` language extension, is require that any time an `Edge` is constructed, the type it's constructed with meets the restriction `(Label l)`. You do that like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

class (Eq l, Show l) => Label l -- assume there might be some `where ...`

data Edge l where
  Edge :: (Label l) => (Int, l, Int) -> Edge l

type Graph l = [Edge l]  -- does not implicitly provide a (Label l)
                         -- constraint on the type, but any actual object
                         -- will necessarily meet that type

instance Show (Edge l) where
  show (Edge a) = "Edge " ++ show a

addEdge :: Graph l -> Edge l -> Graph l
addEdge g e = e : g

data MyLabel = A | B | C deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Label MyLabel

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ addEdge [] $ Edge (1, A, 2) -- producing Graph MyLabel
--    print $ addEdge [] $ Edge (1, 3, 2) -- not passing type checks
```

Note that I had to add an instance for `Show (Edge l)` - if you need them, you'll need to manually make instances for `Eq` and `Ord` too.

Now, what I said above about this providing a constraint on the constructor but not the type: let's imagine that there's a method added to `Label l` like this:

```
class (Eq l, Show l) => Label l where
  defLabel :: l
```

With the instance declaration for `Label MyLabel` modified to say:

```
instance Label MyLabel where
  defLabel = A
```

Then if you tried to write this method, it wouldn't work:

```
newGraph :: Int -> Graph l  -- won't work with this type
newGraph n = zipWith (\f t -> Edge (f, defLabel, t)) [1..n-1] [2..]
```

Instead, you'd need to add the `(Label l)` constraint as:

```
newGraph :: (Label l) => Int -> Graph l  -- works with this type
newGraph n = zipWith (\f t -> Edge (f, defLabel, t)) [1..n-1] [2..]
```

However, if you're dealing only with already constructed `Edge`s, you can rely on an implicit `(Label l)` being used when the `Edge` was constructed. For example, this compiles:

```
isAllDefault :: Graph l -> Bool  -- Look, no Label constraint
isAllDefault [] = True
isAllDefault (Edge (_, l, _):gs) = l == defLabel && isAllDefault gs
                        -- but I can still use defLabel here
                        -- and can rely on (Eq l) from the Label definition
```

---

Style note: Most people would write the `Edge` constructor as:

```
  Edge :: (Label l) => Int -> l -> Int -> Edge l
```

so that you'd then invoke it as `Edge 2 A 1`. I chose to use a tuple to make some code above that wasn't the main point of this answer shorter, but as a matter of general Haskell style you should know that tuples as input types are frowned upon.